# Typing in web forms lagging - output very slow!

Tags: memory, internet-explorer-8

Just recently, typing in forms on the internet has become rediculously slow.

I'm on an oldish PC with low memory (1gb) and amd athlon XP 2800+ (2.08 ghz) and get an awesome 1.0 rating from windows :)

Thing is though - it only just started happening. Was fine last week.

Also, It doesn't only happen when heaps of other processes are open/running. I can have only one IE window up, after fresh reboot, and still happens.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be a problem with your keyboard? I had a 4 year-old wireless keyboard that was giving me input lag & being very resistant to typing, not only on the web but in Word, etc.  Anyway, I replaced it the other week and I can once again type quickly. :)

As a sort of non-problem-solving answer, can you switch to [Google Chrome/Chromium](http://www.google.com/chrome)?  It's blindingly fast (certainly much faster than IE8) and doesn't use a lot of resources (especially the newest developer builds).

Comment: +1 for testing another browser. I'm pretty sure his problem is not IE.

Answer (score 1):

Check your AddIns and/or Toolbars which are installed, might be that there's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset IE8 setting to default, delete the browsing cache and history,

and maybe you may have some luck by desactivating the *Autocomplete fetature* (under Internet option >> content >> utocomplete setting). and turn off all unused accelerators a add-ons.

should work fine now.